# Как добавить массив данных только в одну ячейку?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

Я использую [excel4node](https://github.com/natergj/excel4node#readme).

У меня есть отчет, который формируется по дате и по каждой бригаде за день отчета. Так же имеется таблица `regime`, где могут содержаться несколько записей только для одной бригады. И теперь мне нужно весь этот массив данных  из таблицы `regime` добавить только в одну ячейку.

Но вместо этого в ячейку добавляется только одна последняя запись, а не весь массив.

Т.е такая запись добавляется в ячейку:

> 5LZ 178-1010

А должна добавляться в одну ячейку следующая запись:

> US- 166
>
> 5LZ 178-1010

Как это исправить?

```
rep4Hours.forEach((repHour, index) => {
    repHour._previousDataValues.regimes.forEach((regime) => {
        ws.cell(index + 6, 4).string(regime.spr_turbodrill.turbodrill_name + '- ' + regime.spr_turbodrill.turbodrill_n).style(styleBody)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом цикле вы перезаписывате содержимое ячейки, вместо того чтобы к нему добавлять:

```
repHour._previousDataValues.regimes.forEach((regime) => {
        ws.cell(index + 6, 4).string(regime.spr_turbodrill.turbodrill_name + '- ' + regime.spr_turbodrill.turbodrill_n).style(styleBody)
    })
```

Создайте буферную переменную, выполните в нее конкатенацию всех объектов и потом положите ее в ячейку.

```
rep4Hours.forEach((repHour, index) => {
var temp="";
repHour._previousDataValues.regimes.forEach((regime) => {
        temp=temp+regime.spr_turbodrill.turbodrill_name + '- ' + regime.spr_turbodrill.turbodrill_n;
    })
ws.cell(index + 6, 4).string(temp).style(styleBody);
})
```